# How to find distance between specific element and 1's? - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, distance

Lets say I have a list:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1]
index = 2
```

How do I find the distance between each 1 and my index?
For example What is the distance between [0] and [2] or [2] and [4] or [2] and [6]? (the [0], [4], and [6] are all 1's, and the [2] is my index value.)

The output in this case should look something like this:

```
>> [2, 2, 4]
```

Sorry, I'm really new to Stack Overflow so please excuse me for any flaw I may have in my question writing skills.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for, but I think you have to post your own code next time. :)

```
list1 = [1, 2, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1]
index = 2

result = []

for idx, val in enumerate(list1):
    if val == 1:
        result.append(abs(index - idx))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. I don't know if there is a fancy way to do this (with this I mean a built in function). I would do like this:

```
lis1 = [1, 2, 8, 0, 1, 0, 1]
index = 2
indexes = []

for loop_index, item in list1:
    if item == index:
        indexes.append(loop_index)
```

Having those values appended to the indexes array, you could make the difference of those values on another loop, using the same logics